# Delphi XE 2010: Access Violation - How to remove package or component?

Tags: compiler-errors, crash, package, delphi-xe, access-violation

Well, while back I was setting up my Delphi XE compiler and installed or added all the available packages on my computer system. Everything went well until I installed a packaged called coreide150.bpl. Compiler complained and so, I removed it. However, compiler still raising this error and then it crashes. It only happens when I go to shut the compiler down. It is very annoying. I looked around for help, but nothing seem to help. What can do to resolve this issue?

Delph XE 2010 version 7.0.307

[image: First error popup][image]

Comment: What version are you using. There is no XE 2010. You don't install coreide, it's part of the product. Whatever you have done, and it's not clear, it is probably best to start again. Reinstall.

Comment: Well, when I look under About, it says Delphi XE 2010.

Comment: No such version. Looks like XE.

Answer (score -1):

I am using DELPHI XE2 (and hopefully it is the same for your DELPHI XE).

On the IDE Mainmenu there you should look under Components -> Install Packages.

A list of all installed Packages will appear. Search if you find your Coreide150.
Select it and then click on remove.
If the error continues you may need to reinstall Delphi completely.
Does it only happen with an existing project,
or does it also happen when you create a complete new project from scratch?

Comment: Coreide package isn't one that can be removed.

Comment: @W.Zehntner I did look under installed packages and it is not listed there. The compiler works as it should no problem. This only comes up when I shutdown the compiler. It happens for all or any project I work on.

Comment: How and why did you come to install the Coreide150 ? When you removed it later, there still seem to be some leftovers somewhere in your system. A completly new re-install may be your only choice.